# osx sierra ethereum wallet not syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

running osx sierra.

i am using time server.

canyouseeme.com says 30303 is visible when running geth from command line.

i have completely removed Mist application support directory and tried reinstalling.

running latest 0.8.1 build.

running geth with high verbosity i see something like ...

`I0721 08:49:46.784487 eth/downloader/downloader.go:292] Synchronisation already in progress
I0721 08:49:46.785066 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node 5d643a0e4c5429fb4df58b36eb76ea72f66b7d4e4df522409578daed4c08951170cd46ce0cd2ee0912671d142c1d1609de57261616f0c048043c88884ce751ec: leveldb: not found
I0721 08:49:46.785092 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding 5d643a0e4c5429fb: known=false, fails=0 age=408087h49m46.78508933s
I0721 08:49:46.943324 eth/fetcher/fetcher.go:368] [eth/62] Peer 2af714fc4d4952a1: discarded announcement #1926565 [28190a28…], distance 1926565
I0721 08:49:47.237290 p2p/discover/udp.go:453] >>> 113.106.85.172:30303 discover.pong
I0721 08:49:47.237399 p2p/discover/udp.go:521] <<< 113.106.85.172:30303 *discover.ping: ok
I0721 08:49:47.238229 p2p/discover/table.go:473] Bonding 68dd1360f0a4ac36: known=true, fails=0 age=97h13m45.238223979s
I0721 08:49:47.363516 eth/fetcher/fetcher.go:368] [eth/62] Peer 865cda0c7c2fb72f: discarded announcement #1926565 [28190a28…], distance 1926565
I0721 08:49:47.536308 p2p/discover/database.go:183] failed to retrieve node 5d643a0e4c5429fb4df58b36eb76ea72f66b7d4e4df522409578daed4c08951170cd46ce0cd2ee0912671d142c1d1609de57261616f0c048043c88884ce751ec: leveldb: not found
I0721 08:49:47.536337 p2p/discover/udp.go:521] <<< 77.180.183.107:30303 *discover.findnode: unknown node
I1231 16:00:00.000000 eth/downloader/downloader.go:284] Attempting synchronisation: 78129e171bb7484a, head [28190a28…], TD 39873023365438740184
I1231 16:00:00.000000 eth/downloader/downloader.go:292] Synchronisation already in progress
I1231 16:00:00.000000 eth/fetcher/fetcher.go:713] Peer 78129e171bb7484a: discarded block #1926565 [28190a28…], distance 1926565`

Comment: after installing leveldb through macports, i am avoiding that line in the log at least, but still no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, updates to ethereum (and possibly OSX) seems to have resolved this. I am no longer having issues.